# Group this JSON job listing by Team

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON and I'd like to group the listings by team, like on [this page](https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/leverdemo?group=team&mode=json):

- Team Name

  - Job Title
  - Job Title
  - Job Title
- Team Name

  - Job Title
- Team Name

  - Job Title

The following is from their documentation:

HTML:

```
<head>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>  
<section>
  <div class="container" id="jobs-container">
    <h1>Open jobs</h1>
    <div class="jobs-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
// REPLACE "LEVERDEMO" WITH YOUR COMPANY NAME BELOW
url = 'https://api.lever.co/v0/postings/leverdemo?mode=json'


//Setting up the structure for each job posting
function createJobs(_data) {
  for(i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
    var posting = _data[i] 
    var title = posting.text
    var description = posting.description  
    //Making each job description shorter than 250 characters
    var shortDescription = $.trim(description).substring(0, 250)
    .replace('\n', ' ') + "...";
    var location = posting.categories.location
    var commitment = posting.categories.commitment
    var team = posting.categories.team
    var link = posting.hostedUrl

    $('#jobs-container .jobs-list').append(
      '<div class="job '+team+' '+location+' '+commitment+'">' +
        '<a class="job-title" href="'+link+'"">'+title+'</a>' +
        '<p class="tags"><span>'+team+'</span><span>'+location+'</span><span>'+commitment+'</span></p>' +
        '<p class="description">'+shortDescription+'</p>' +
        '<a class="btn" href="'+link+'">Learn more</a>' +
      '</div>'  

    );
  }
}

//Fetching job postings from Lever's postings API
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  success: function(data){
    createJobs(data);}
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Link to Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/andreasmb/pen/uogcI).

Comment: I tried nesting for loops. I kind of got it working, but it was only showing one job per team.

Comment: Added proper link formatting

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had the same problem.
Here is my resolution:

```
function createJobs(joblist) {
for (i = 0; i < joblist.length; i++) {
    jobstring = '<div class="team"><h2>' + joblist[i].title + '</h2>';
    for (j = 0; j < joblist[i].postings.length; j++) {
        jobstring += '<a href="#" class="job">' +  joblist[i].postings[j].categories.commitment + ' ' + joblist[i].postings[j].text + '<br/></a><br/> '; 
    }
    jobstring += '</div>'
    $('#jobs-container').append(jobstring);
}
}
```

Hope this helps you.